# Resizing the 'Save As' window in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window

How can I resize the 'Save as' window so it only fills perhaps somewhere around 25% of the computer screen, or whatever the default size for that window is?

I am running Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1 on a Dell Vostro 460 PC.  I am downloading journal articles from the Internet and saving them as PDFs.  Somehow I unintentionally clicked a button that resulted in the 'Save as' window filling the entire screen of my computer, except for the toolbar at the very bottom.

One suggestion I found was to grab the bottom of the window with the mouse and scroll upward until the window was the desired size.  That does not appear to be possible in my case. Another suggestion was to click on the window with the middle mouse button before attempting to resize the window, but that does not help either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The window is maximized. You can unmaximize it using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> or by double-clicking the title bar. (That there is no unmaximize button and the resizer doesn't work can certainly be considered a bug.)

Comment: Dragging the toolbar does nothing for the maximised window. Win+Down (or double-clicking the toolbar) works, as it is the shortcut for @elkhorn's answer. What is confusing is the fact that the window is in maximised state without it taking up the entire screen, so I didn't think it is maximised (it even has a grip in the corner). Possible windows bug?

Comment: Thank you, user3463!  Five years later, this bug is still present in Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, and your solution (WindowsKey+DownArrow) still works.

Answer (score 4):

This works for Windows 8 - it may help you on other windows versions. Click Alt-spacebar. you should get the little action box in the upper left of the screen. Click on Restore. This should re-size the save as window, and allow you to use the mouse to drag the screen size to your desired size.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Double-click the window's top bar.

Got this tip from [pcreview.co.uk forums](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/save-dialog-box-resize-t3604908.html):

> **Question:** When saving emails from Outlook, the Save As dialog box goes full screen, and
>   I can't get it to resize smaller to normal dialog box size. […] There seems to be no option to minimize or maximize.
>
> **Answer:** Double click on the title bar to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

I right-clicked the title bar, and a menu popped up. I clicked Size on that menu, and then I could regular-click the corners of the window and drag them back to a smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine smaller by clicking the hide folder button in the bottom left corner. After it resized, I clicked show folders again.