# 'Save As/Open With' Windows are huge and zoomed in

Tags: windows-10

I recently reinstalled Windows 10, and I have noticed that my 'Save As/Open With' or similar popup windows are very zoomed in with very large text. This is an example of how it looks if I try to save a web page on Chrome.

Example: 
[image]

My resolution is set to 1080p and I have the adjustment slider at 100%. How can I fix it so that it is normal size with respect to everything else?

Comment: Have you tried resizing the Save As window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing the 'Save As' window in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/417867/resizing-the-save-as-window-in-windows-7)

Comment: Resizing does not change the font sizes and boxes back to normal. It makes the window smaller and decreases the space that shows the folder items without fixing the scaling.

Answer (score 3):

I had success with this:

1. Open file location of chrome.exe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application)
2. Right click and open the properties
3. Select the compatibility tab
4. Click "Change high DPI settings"
5. Check the "Override high DPI scaling behavior" box
6. Set "Scaling performed by:" to "System"
7. Restart

Comment: The same options exist for FireFox and other applications. Worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just Click mouse in the corner and resize as you want !

[image]

(if you cant do that, then at first,  Right click on any empty place of the "SAVE AS" window, and choose SIZE, and then do it again)

Comment: Resizing does not change the font sizes and boxes back to normal. It makes the window smaller and decreases the space that shows the folder items without fixing the scaling.